# 1) Backup of Form library in Sharepoint 2010 with metadata

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, infopath-rules

How to take a backup and restore infopath form library in Sharepoint 2010 without losing Metadata (Modified, Created, modified by and Created By ) fields.

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can save your Form library as a template with "Include Content".

Go to **Form Library-> Library Settings->Save form library as template**.

Then go to list template gallery(http://sp2010/_catalogs/lt/forms/AllItems.aspx), we can download the .stp template file and backup it.

[image]

You can also use PowerShell or SharePoint Central Administration to export the list.

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity <SiteURL> -Path <Path and File Name> [-ItemUrl <URL of Site, List, or Library>] [-IncludeUserSecurity] [-IncludeVersions] [-NoFileCompression] [-GradualDelete] [-Verbose]
```

More information: [Export sites, lists, or document libraries in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/export-a-site-list-or-document-library)

Comment: This process overrides metadata.

Comment: I modify the reply, we can also use PowerShell or Central Administration to export the list to a .cmp file.

Comment: powershell script also overrides metadata